# Unable to start an NServiceBus Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, nservicebus

### Problem Description

I have a Windows service which is hosting an NServiceBus endpoint in NServiceBus.Host.exe.

The binaries are deployed to `c:\inetpub\bus\services\myService` folder on the server.

A DSC script makes sure the Windows service is created/exists on the server, with the "path to executable" property of the service set to `"c:\inetpub\bus\services\myService´NServiceBus.Host.exe" -service NServicebus.Production`.

**Note!** The `-service` switch is added when installing the service by using the built-in `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` parameter, which is why I added it to the Windows service executable path in the DSC script.

Now, when I try to start the service manually on the server, it yields the following error message

```
Windows could not start the <service name> service on the Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

### Debugging Steps

I have looked through the event log and the following two error messages sticks out:

**NServiceBust.Host.exe error:**

```
Application: NServiceBus.Host.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: 

Topshelf.Exceptions.ConfigurationException
at Topshelf.Internal.Actions.RunAsServiceAction.Do(Topshelf.Configuration.IRunConfiguration)
   at Topshelf.Runner.Host(Topshelf.Configuration.IRunConfiguration, System.String[])
   at NServiceBus.Host.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

**Local Activation permission error:**

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID

{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160} 

and APPID

{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}

to the user <my_service_account_user> SID (<service_account_SID>) from
address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified
using the Component Services administrative tool.`
```

**Note!** The error above only occurs once, i.e. the first time I try to start the service. It does not appear again in the event log for any subsequent attempts of starting the service.

What I have done so far:

1. Tried the suggestions in [a closely related post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408585/why-does-a-windows-service-hosting-an-nservicebus-endpoint-in-nservicebus-host), none of which were working.
2. Tried to install the service by using using the `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` parameter. In this case, the service name is created with its name on the following format: `MyService.EndpointConfig_v1.0.0.0`. Using this approach, the service starts successfully without any error message

   - Stopping the service and then try to start the service created by the DSC script (with a different name) => success
   - Removing the service created by NServiceBus and then trying to start the DSC-created service again => failure
3. Tried granting the service account used for logon when running the service various privileges (neither of which yielded any success), among others:

   - Membership in the Administrators group
   - Membership in the Performance Log Users group
   - Full DCOM permissions via "Launch and Activation Permissions" in `dcomcnfg`
4. Tried running `c:\inetpub\bus\services\myService´NServiceBus.Host.exe NServicebus.Production` from the CLI => success

### Code

My `Init()` method for the service looks like this:

```cs
namespace MyService
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomLogging, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => XmlConfigurator.Configure(File.OpenRead(@"log4net.config")));

            GlobalContext.Properties["Hostname"] = Dns.GetHostName();
            GlobalContext.Properties["Service"] = typeof(EndpointConfig).Namespace;

            var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());

            Configure.With()
                .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport()
                    .IsTransactional(true)
                    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                    .IsolationLevel(System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);

            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<some_conn_string>"].ConnectionString;
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IDatabaseProvider>()
                         .ImplementedBy<DatabaseProvider>()
                         .DependsOn(Property.ForKey("connectionString").Eq(connectionString)));
        }
    }
}
```

### Theory

When installing the service using `/install` I assume that NServiceBus.Host.exe does some black magic under the hood - e.g. grants some necessary permissions - to make the service able to start.

**Note!** On the server, the latest version of NServiceBus is installed (v6.x). However, in my solution/service project version 2.x is used (please, do not ask if I can upgrade - unfortunately, that is not an option).

Appreciate any help I can get, as I am running out of ideas.

### EDIT 1

I was asked why I can't just use the `/install` parameter of NServiceBus and be happy with that. The answer to that is that I could (and, actually, I currently am).

The reason I have still posted this question is split:

1. I wish to understand why one of two seemingly equivalent approaches fails
2. I am not completely happy with using the `/install` parameter. The reason? It boils down to a "chicken or the egg" problem. I use Powershell DSC to provision servers in Azure and I believe that ensuring that Windows Services exists on the server is the responsibility of DSC. However, the first time a server is provisioned the services cannot exist unless I script their creation with DSC, and point the executable path to where the service binaries will be deployed whenever that happens. The other alternative is to skip service creation in DSC, and run the `NServiceBus.Host.exe /install` as a part of the service/application deployment script instead. Obviously, deployment cannot happen until after a server has been provisioned. Thus, it requires the Windows Service part of the DSC script being stripped down to e.g. merely ensuring the service exist - a verification which will fail until a first time deployment of the application has been performed.

Comment: Why can't you use the NServiceBus.Host.exe /install?

Comment: @SeanFarmar: I tried to elaborate a bit regarding your question. See "Edit 1", please.

Comment: Did you look at [self hosting](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/#self-hosting)? It seems a lot better aligned with what you are trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option (I am working with legacy applications here, and it would take too much effort to re-write them all).

Comment: What is the environment? You say 'server'. Does the installation work on other servers/desktops?

Googling on the error messages returns this : https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/windows-10-event-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-d63b10c5-bb46-4990-a94f-e40b9d520160-and-a/

Also, this is the source of the installer for v2.0 for you to inspect https://github.com/ramonsmits/NServiceBus/tree/2.0/src/host/NServiceBus.Host

Comment: @RamonSmits: The environment is Windows Server 2016. The service installation works on other servers when using the `/install` parameter (this way of installing the service has never been the issue). Thnx for supplying the source for the v2.0 installer, I'll have a look as soon as I can.